# How to process a json response from an API in C#

Tags: c#, json

I've read and reread articles online on how to do this, but it's probably something simple.  I'm trying to learn how to process a json response from an API call.  I have a simple method I call from Main()

```
       public async void apiTestCall()
    {
        var httpCall = new HttpClient();
        var uri = new Uri("https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?sol=1000&page=2&api_key=DEMO_KEY");
        var result = new DataModel();

        var response = await httpCall.GetStringAsync(uri);
        result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DataModel>(response);
```

I am expecting "result" to be a DataModel object with the data populated.  Right now, there is nothing.
[image]

Here is the DataModel class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace APITestProject
{
    class DataModel
    {
        public class Camera
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int rover_id { get; set; }
            public string full_name { get; set; }
        }

        public class Rover
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string landing_date { get; set; }
            public string launch_date { get; set; }
            public string status { get; set; }
        }

        public class Photo
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public int sol { get; set; }
            public Camera camera { get; set; }
            public string img_src { get; set; }
            public string earth_date { get; set; }
            public Rover rover { get; set; }
        }

        public class Example
        {
            public IList<Photo> photos { get; set; }
        }


    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

***Edit #1:*** Here is the first 3 entries in the json.  I didn't want to post the whole thing but the URL is valid for anyone to run and see the response.

```
{"photos":[{"id":424926,"sol":1000,"camera":{"id":22,"name":"MAST","rover_id":5,"full_name":"Mast Camera"},"img_src":"http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/msss/01000/mcam/1000ML0044631200305217E01_DXXX.jpg","earth_date":"2015-05-30","rover":{"id":5,"name":"Curiosity","landing_date":"2012-08-06","launch_date":"2011-11-26","status":"active"}},{"id":424927,"sol":1000,"camera":{"id":22,"name":"MAST","rover_id":5,"full_name":"Mast Camera"},"img_src":"http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/msss/01000/mcam/1000MR0044631190503679E04_DXXX.jpg","earth_date":"2015-05-30","rover":
```

**Edit #2:** I made some changes based on the comments so far and I used the Paste > Special > JSON as Classes and removed the "wrapper" class. Now I get the populated object.  FYI, here is the new class VS generated:

```
namespace APITestProject
{

    public class DataModel
    {
        public Photo[] photos { get; set; }
    }

    public class Photo
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int sol { get; set; }
        public Camera camera { get; set; }
        public string img_src { get; set; }
        public string earth_date { get; set; }
        public Rover rover { get; set; }
    }

    public class Camera
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int rover_id { get; set; }
        public string full_name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rover
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string landing_date { get; set; }
        public string launch_date { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the JSON to the question?

Comment: Classes within classes is not a very common convention in  c# and we haven't seen your json, but the serializer looks for fields and properties, not internal classes.

Comment: that makes sense @Crowcoder.  I used an online class generator to create the DataModel.

Comment: I also think DataModel has to be public

Comment: You put yourself (or the online converter you used, there's one that uses `Example` as the JSON Root) the `Example` class. That's what you should deserialize to, `DataModel.Example`.

Comment: @Crowcoder No, it doesn't. It's assumed the deserializer belongs to a class in the same namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You class `DataModel` just defines other classes, but do not **instance** them.

According to the data inside the response, you `DataModel` class should have at least `Photos` member. It could be type of `List<Photo>`

```
class DataModel {
     ...
    public List<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
}
```

The `Photos` definition says, that there is some list of photos of `Photo` type to be expected.

Comment: The "Photos" field needs to be all lowercase so it will match the JSON.

Comment: Not necessarily. Depends on the JsonSerializer settings. Usually it converts pascal case to camel case and vice versa. Therefore I prefer C# way - PascalCase. But of course, it can be also lower.

Comment: Json.Net is case-insensitive, while System.Text.Json, the one the OP is using, is not; add `[JsonPropertyName("photos")]` eventually.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try the following amendment

```
var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DataModel.Example>(response);
```

as it looks like DataModel.Example is actually the class that you are trying to deserialize to based on the response that comes from the following call -

https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?sol=1000&page=2&api_key=DEMO_KEY

i.e. It returns an object containing an array of photo objects as you have defined them. As someone else mentioned, no need to encapsulate all of these classes within another class.

Comment: Agreed. I tried it and works like a charm.